How can prevent Sphinx from converting the characters?
Edit a file in python-sphinx:
vim test.rst
test
==============
it's  a "test"

The ' and " convert into ’ and “ such as below after "make html":
it’s a “test”

How can prevent Sphinx from converting the characters?How can get the output?
it's a "test"


You should be able to escape the quotes or disable/adjust smart quotes as a configuration. Also see this older post and this more recent one.
